# Whom should I contact if I want to create a legal gambling business with an offshore company?

Tags: gambling

I'm interested in creating a legal gambling business. What kind of lawyer should I contact in order to make everything legal?

Answer (score 1):

One good strategy is to find a successful business similar to the one you want to create. Then, with some digging around, you can find out which law firm/s represent/s them. Then call them.

Another approach is to search the Google term [`offshore gambling attorney`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=offshore%20gambling%20attorneys&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) then just start reading and contact the ones that seem knowledgable in the specifics that affect your business.